# Different ViewController called when TableView is Editing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, editing

I have a simple grouped table view that when a cell is selected it pushes a View controller. The navigation bar's left item puts the table view in "editing mode." In editing mode you can move and delete each cell as wanted. What I want is to be able to push a separate View controller when it is editing mode then when it is in normal mode.

This is where the View Controller is being pushed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...stuff that doesnt matter...

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];


}
```

The BarButtonItems are being declared here:

```
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];
```

This is where all the editing stuff is declared:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [atableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView 
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
  toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] moveItemAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row] 
                                    toIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push your view controller in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can check if the tableview is in editing mode. If it is, you can push a different view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      ...stuff that doesnt matter...
         if(aTableView.editing) // The tableview is in editing mode
      [[self navigationController] pushViewController:otherViewController animated:YES];
      else [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];


}
```

editing is a property that returns YES if the tableview is currently in editing mode.

Comment: Thanks for the help but Its doesnt seem to work. I cant select the table cell while its in editing mode and I havnt made the view controller yet but I did if(atableView.editing) { NSLog(@"editing")}    and didnt get any feedback...